# Confused with calling JQuery custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have html like so

```
<span rel='comm' val='12'>click</span>
<span rel='comm' val='82'>click</span>
```

and I am using JQuery to do this

```
$('span[rel*=comm]').cust();
```

and the custom function is as such

```
$.fn.cust = function () {

    $(this).click(function(e) {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
}
```

The value of this is 12 even when I click on 2nd span which should give me 82

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to return a seperate function for each element in the collection, normally done with `return this.each ...`

```
$.fn.cust = function () {
   return this.each(function() {
      $(this).click(function(e){
          alert($(this).val());
       });
   });
}
```

And `value` is not a valid attribute for a `span` element.

Comment: @user1690718 - see the link by Matt Ball in the comments. And your HTML is'nt valid !

Comment: yes i know :) just needed to give an example , im recovering attr value  chhers

Comment: @user1690718 - If you intend to use `attr('value')`, that's a hack for something that is inherently wrong and invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This should work better:

```
$.fn.cust = function () {
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        alert($(this).attr('val'));
    });
}
```

span does not have *value*.

http://jsfiddle.net/dREj6/

Also if you want to make your method chainable you should return an jQuery instance:

```
$.fn.cust = function () {
    return $(this).click(function (e) {
        alert($(this).attr('val'));
    });
}

$('span[rel*=comm]').cust().css('color', 'red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dREj6/1/

Answer (score 0):

- `rel` are for links (anchor element) - use `class`
- use `data` attribute instead of custom attributes

http://jsbin.com/ogenev/1/edit

```
<span class='comm' data-val='12'>click</span>
<span class='comm' data-val='82'>click</span>
```

```
$.fn.cust = function(){

   $(this).click(function(){
      alert(this.dataset.val);
   });

};


$('.comm').cust();
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use `.attr('val')`

```
$.fn.cust = function () {

    $(this).click(function(e){
      alert($(this).attr('val'));
    });
}
$('span[rel*=comm]').cust();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fW7FT/

`.val()` is for `input` since they're the only one accepting the `val` attribute *officialy*

Answer (score 0):

The call `$('span[rel*=comm]')` returns a **JQuery wrapper** for all spans matching the selector - the two ones you have in your example are picked both.

Now inside the definition of `cust`, `$(this)` refers to the wrapped array, which causes your issue. Use

```
$(this).each( function() { 
     $(this).click (...
});
```

Inisde `each` `$(this)` will point to each separate span element in the selection, so they will have the `click` handler individually attached and working as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you're looking for with this:

HTML:

```
<span rel='comm' val='12'>click</span>
<span rel='comm' val='82'>click</span>
```

JS:

```
var cust = function(source) {
  alert($(source).attr('val'));
}

$('span[rel*=comm]').click(function(e) {
 cust(this);
});
```

The JSFiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/ejquB/